# React-router same url not remounting, trying to figure out componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm working on my first React app and having some troubles with routing, just looking for some guidance. I see that this is a specific problem for a lot of people, but having trouble following along with other answers.

From what I can tell of other answers, people are assigning keys to specific routes, and checking the key in componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps). I kinda get that, although not sure where to go from there in terms of re-rendering/mounting.

I'm simply trying to transition between the URLs `/catalog/genre/:genre` and `/catalog/genres`. Sorry in advance for the messy code, just trying to get it working!

App.js contains main routes, more specifically for this problem:

`<Route path="/catalog/genres" component={Genres}/>`

Genres.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Link,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

class Genre extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/catalog/genre/58eacca74a0d2c105c68fbe9')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        data: json.genre_books
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log(newProps.params);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          Genre:
          <label>
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.data.map((piece) =>
                  <Link key={piece._id} to={`${piece.url}`}>
                    <li>
                      {piece.title}
                    </li>
                  </Link>
                )
              }
            </ul>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AllGenres extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/catalog/genres')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        data: json.genres_list
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        All Genres:
        <label>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.data.map((piece) =>
                <Link key={piece._id} to={`${piece.url}`}>
                  <li>
                    {piece.name}
                  </li>
                </Link>
              )
            }
          </ul>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Genres extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/catalog/genres')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        data: json.genres_list
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path="/catalog/genre/:genre" render={() => (
              <Genre testKey='1'/>
            )}/>
            <Route exact path="/catalog/genres" render={() => (
              <AllGenres testKey='2' />
            )}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Genres;
```

Answer (score 0):

For people coming back to this problem, although componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) is useful for other situations, I found a way around this by following this
[guide](https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669).

Now I'm able to render based on the URL parameter `genreId`.

Here's the code:

App.js Nav component

```
class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tap: 0,
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <Router>
            <div style={styles.mainContent}>
              <Drawer open="TRUE" title="My App">
                <MenuItem primaryText="Home" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/home" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="All books" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/books" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="All authors" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/authors" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="All genres" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/genres" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="All book-instances" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/bookinstances" />} />
                <hr></hr>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Create new author" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/author/create" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Create new genre" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/genre/create" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Create new book" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/book/create" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Create new book instance (copy)" containerElement={<Link to="/catalog/bookinstance/create" />} />
                <hr></hr>
                <MenuItem primaryText="About" containerElement={<Link to="/about" />} />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Topics" containerElement={<Link to="/topics" />} />
              </Drawer>

              <Route path="/catalog/home" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/catalog/books" component={Books}/>
              <Route path="/catalog/authors" component={Authors}/>
              <Route path="/catalog/genres" component={Genres}/>
              <Route path="/catalog/bookInstances" component={BookInstances}/>
              <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
              <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Genres.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';

class GenreList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/catalog/genres')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        data: json.genres_list
      });
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        All Genres:
        <label>
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.data.map((piece) =>
                <Link key={piece._id} to={`${piece.url}`}>
                  <li>
                    {piece.name}
                  </li>
                </Link>
              )
            }
          </ul>
        </label>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Genre = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.genreId}</h3>
  </div>
)

const Genres = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Route path={`${match.url}/:genreId`} component={Genre}/>

        <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
          <div>
            <GenreList url={match.url}/>
          </div>
        )}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Genres;
```

genre.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GenreSchema = Schema({
 name: { type: String, required: true, min: 3, max: 100 },
}, {
   toObject: {
     virtuals: true
   },
   toJSON: {
     virtuals: true
   } //reference to the associated book
});

// Virtual for bookinstance's URL
GenreSchema
.virtual('url')
.get(function () {
  return '/catalog/genres/' + this._id;
});

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', GenreSchema);
```